# wkhtmltoimage centos 6 error

Tags: php, linux, centos, centos6

I'm trying to get [wkhtmltoimage](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) to work on my CentOS 6 server. I've unpacked the files, however when I run the command I'm getting an error.

The command I'm running is

> wkhtmltoimage-i386 --load-error-handling ignore http://www.google.com/
>   /var/www/vhosts/website.com/httpdocs/img/example.jpg

The error I'm getting is

> wkhtmltoimage-i386: error while loading shared libraries:
>   libfontconfig.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
>   directory

I've followed a number of tutorials but I'm not having much luck. My background is with windows servers, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got same error when I used wkhtmltoimage-i386. I began using this version http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/downloads/detail?name=wkhtmltoimage-0.11.0_rc1-static-amd64.tar.bz2 and it worked. Try it out.

Updated: About this error, you can install the missing library by following command:
On CentOs:
yum install libfontconfig.so.1

or on others:
apt-get install libfontconfig.so.1